# Swagger : Generate a multiple example with IMultipleExamplesProvider with Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters .net core web Api 3.1

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-core, swagger

In Swagger To generate a multiple examples with IMultipleExamplesProvider  with Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters  did not work :

public class ValueGetProblemDetailsInternalServer :
IMultipleExamplesProvider

```
{

    public IEnumerable<SwaggerExample<ValidationProblemDetailsInternalServer>> GetExamples()
    {

        yield return SwaggerExample.Create(
        "xxxx",
       "yyyy",
        new ValidationProblemDetailsInternalServer()
        {
            Type = "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.21v",
            Title = "Erreur lors du traitement de la requête",
            Detail = "Une ou plusieurs erreurs sont survenues lors du traitement de la requête.",
            Status = (int?)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
            Instance = "personne/12345678902"

        });

        yield return SwaggerExample.Create(
        "vxwcvxcv",
        "helloxcv",
      new ValidationProblemDetailsInternalServer()
      {
          Type = "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.21vcc",
          Title = "Erreur lors du traitement de la requête2",
          Detail = "Une ou plusieurs erreurs sont survenues lors du traitement de la requête2.",
          Status = (int?)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
          Instance = "personne/12345678902k"

      });
    }
}
```

and in startup:
services.AddSwaggerExamplesFromAssemblyOf(typeof(ValueGetProblemDetailsInternalServer));

Thanks to help me.

Comment: Is this the same question as [your previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68635426/113116)?

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into the same problem.

According to the documentation, one needs to call **c.ExampleFilters()** method to register the example providers.

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    // Note: Required when using example providers
    c.ExampleFilters();
}

services.AddSwaggerExamplesFromAssemblies(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());
```